# Join on table with more joining attributes

Tags: sql-server

I have table `App` with applications (`AppID, RequestDt, OrgID`), a table `Branch` with the names of branch (`branch_id, branch_name`) and `Wspace` with employees (`branchID, NmbrEmp`)

```
select  
    substring(b.RequestDt,1,6) as Date,
    a.branch_name,
    d.NmbrEmp,
    COUNT(b.AppId) as TotalApp,
    SUM(convert(int,b.OKFlg)) as TotalAppOK
    SUM(convert(int,b.NotOKFlg)) as TotalAppNOK, 
from    
    App b 
join 
    Branch a on a.branch_id  = b.OrgId 
left join 
    WSpace d on a.branch_id = d.branchID 
where 
    substring(b.RequestDt,1,6) >= 201301
group by 
    substring(b.RequestDt,1,6), a.branch_name, d.NmbrEmp
```

This select will return : (I show only example of two rows in reality there is more then 1000)

```
   Date    Branch    NmbrEmp        TotalApp    TotalAppOK  TotalAppNOK
   --------------------------------------------------------------------
    201402  Home        5             28        20            8
    201402  Office      4             15         8            7
    201403  Home        5             24         7            17
    201403  Office      4             30         9            21
```

Now I want to add next column with `INFO`. This `INFO` is in another table called `App2` which contains only specific applications (`AppID, INFO`)

I want count row where the INFO is 1 from table App2 and just  put that number into next column for each row.

But every time it messes up my original group by ... That's because in App2 are only "OKApps" (plus there are apps that are not in App at all) so when I do:

```
join App2 c on b.APPId = c.APPId
```

my NOTOK Apps will disappear from group by and when I do left join I have more apps then before ...

Thank you for your help

Comment: why not just `COUNT` this before this `SELECT` and put into it as some variable?

Comment: Can you show the tables' structure while I'm working on the answer?

Comment: Try forming the group by APPID and count in the separate table and join with the APPID to this available result

Comment: Thank you for the tips , ill try it in 30mins and ill let you know.

Comment: I think i explained it badly.I want know how many applications in each original agregation have Info = 1 in table App2. That means in row : "201402, Home, 5, 28, 20 ,8," i have agregated 28 applications and i want to know how many of them are in table App2 with INFO = 1 . And in App table are AppIDs that are not in App2 table at all and in App2 table are AppIDs that are not in App table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like I said in the comment you can use like variable or just add with `CROSS JOIN`:

```
DECLARE @someTable TABLE ([Date] VARCHAR(10), Branch VARCHAR(10), NmbrEmp INT, TotalApp INT, TotalAppOK INT, TotalAppNOK INT)

INSERT INTO @someTable SELECT '201402', 'Home', 5, 28, 20, 8
INSERT INTO @someTable SELECT '201402', 'Office', 4, 15, 8, 7
INSERT INTO @someTable SELECT '201403', 'Home', 5, 24, 7, 17
INSERT INTO @someTable SELECT '201403', 'Office', 4, 30, 9, 21



DECLARE @App2 TABLE (AppID INT, INFO INT)

INSERT INTO @App2 SELECT 2, 2
INSERT INTO @App2 SELECT 3, 1
INSERT INTO @App2 SELECT 4, 2

---FIRST CHOICE

DECLARE @App2Count INT = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @App2 WHERE INFO = 2)

SELECT Date, Branch, NmbrEmp, TotalApp, TotalAppOK, TotalAppNOK, @App2Count as App2
FROM @someTable

---SECOND CHOICE
SELECT Date, Branch, NmbrEmp, TotalApp, TotalAppOK, TotalAppNOK, A.App2 as App2
FROM @someTable sT
CROSS JOIN (SELECT COUNT(*) as App2 FROM @App2 WHERE INFO = 2) as A
```

Answer (score 0):

You should just count the `Info`s inside a subquery and join that:

```
select  substring(b.RequestDt,1,6) as Date,
    a.branch_name,
    d.NmbrEmp,
    COUNT(b.AppId) as TotalApp,
    SUM(convert(int,b.OKFlg)) as TotalAppOK
    SUM(convert(int,b.NotOKFlg)) as TotalAppNOK, 
    e.C 
from    
    App b 
join Branch a on a.branch_id  = b.OrgId 
left join WSpace d on a.branch_id = d.branchID 
LEFT JOIN   
    (SELECT COUNT(*) AS C, AppID 
        FROM App2 
        WHERE Info = 1 
        GROUP BY AppId) e 
on e.AppId = b.AppId

where 
    substring(b.RequestDt,1,6) >= 201301
group by 
    substring(b.RequestDt,1,6), a.branch_name, d.NmbrEmp
```